# Select all subtring before a special character

Tags: regex, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have the following text type in a column value.

```
{186=>15.55255158, 21=>5123.43494408, 164=>0.0}
```

I would like to select the numbers before the => character and use the ouput in a subquery. So the output should be:

```
186 
21
164
```

I tried several regex statement but it does not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A simple regex of `(\d+)=>` is enough to extract the numbers you're after into a capture group.

Comment: @PrestonGuillot I tried `select * from () where col_name ~ '(\d+)=>'`. But the output is the same as the input

Comment: You're selecting a row where the value matches what you've given, you're not running any functions to extract the matched values into a set.

Comment: You should store that as a proper JSON value (in a `jsonb` column) that will make your live a lot easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to both use a regular expression, and a function to extract the values matched from the regular expression into a data set. The `~` operator is only used to match in a `where` clause. You need the `REGEXP_MATCHES` function.

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_MATCHES(your_column_name, '(\d+)=>', 'g') 
FROM your_table_name
```

The `'g'` option will return multiple matches, rather than just the first.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/886030/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the simple `substring(column_name from '(\d+)=>')` to extract the appropriate data.

Comment: thank you, this works well for the first occurrence of the pattern in each row. Is there a way to have all the possible occurrence for each rows please?

Comment: You can use regexp_split_to_table as shown below.

```SELECT foo FROM regexp_split_to_table('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog', '\s+') AS foo;
  foo   
-------
 the    
 quick  
 brown  
 fox    
 jumps 
 over   
 the    
 lazy   
 dog
```
Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-matching.html

Comment: Thank you. you answered and I should validate your answer but I am still stuck with this. I pass a subquery instead of a string in the `regexp_split_to_table` function. And it throws me an error: `ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`. It seems I need a kind of loop to go through all rows and use the function.

Comment: 'string_agg(svals::character varying, ' ')' before to input in `regexp_split_to_table()` and it worked